# mediawiki custom menu

Tags: customization, mediawiki

i am playing with some wiki and i am wondering how is made this custom menu:

[erepublik wiki](http://wiki.erepublik.com/index.php/Template%3aGame_Menu)

is it some modification?
I just need hints, links to something.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [template](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aTemplates), made using wiki markup and [parser functions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aExtension%3aParserFunctions).  You can see the code that generates it by clicking the "view source" tab at the top of the page.

Alas, you probably won't find the code very readable unless you're already intimately familiar with MediaWiki template syntax — it's full of metatemplate madness and obscure MediaWiki features.  But it's all there, if you can just make some sense of it.